# Changing dataDir in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have an mysql server and I want to change the datadir from `/var/lib/mysql` to `dif_dir/mysql`. Is it a simple scp? If not, what are the steps that I need to take?

Answer (score 1):

1. Shut down mysql.
2. Copy data, probably via: `$ rsync -avp /path/to/old/loc/ /path/to/new/loc/`
3. Change `my.cnf` to reflect new location.
4. Ensure ownership and permissions on new location are correct and that, if applicable, SELinux and/or apparmor profiles are updated to allow mysql to access the new location.
5. Start up mysql.
6. If all looks good, delete the db files from the old location.

Comment: @Cubatown - you're welcome. Take note of step #4. That one bit me recently.